# Fetching Picture info

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to fetch picture's info using this code.
I'm having trouble getting the link of the picture.

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        task.execute("..."); //I'm not sharing the link here

    }

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = reader.read();

                while (data != -1) {

                    char current = (char) data;

                    result += current;

                    data = reader.read();

                }

                return result;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            try {
```

//Problem must be here :

```
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                String data = jsonObject.getString("data");
                String images = jsonObject.getString("images");
                String standard_resolution = jsonObject.getString("standard_resolution");

                Log.i("Content", data);

                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(standard_resolution);

                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                    Log.i("description", jsonPart.getString("url"));
                    Log.i("description", jsonPart.getString("description"));
```

//till here

```
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
    }


}
```

This is the webpage response.

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "image",
        "users_in_photo": [{
            "user": {
                "username": "kevin",
                "full_name": "Kevin S",
                "id": "3",
                "profile_picture": "..."
            },
            "position": {
                "x": 0.315,
                "y": 0.9111
            }
        }],
        "filter": "Walden",
        "tags": [],
        "comments": {
            "count": 2
        },
        "caption": null,
        "likes": {
            "count": 1
        },
        "link": "http://instagr.am/p/D/",
        "user": {
            "username": "kevin",
            "full_name": "Kevin S",
            "profile_picture": "...",
            "id": "3"
        },
        "created_time": "1279340983",
        "images": {
            "low_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2010/07/16/4de37e03aa4b4372843a7eb33fa41cad_6.jpg",
                "width": 306,
                "height": 306
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2010/07/16/4de37e03aa4b4372843a7eb33fa41cad_5.jpg",
                "width": 150,
                "height": 150
            },
            "standard_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2010/07/16/4de37e03aa4b4372843a7eb33fa41cad_7.jpg",
                "width": 612,
                "height": 612
            }
        },
        "id": "3",
        "location": null
    }
}
```

Comment: The images value is not a string. It's an object. Call the correct methods to parse the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no arrays in the path of the data you want. Just objects

```
String resolution = "standard_resolution";
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
JSONObject images = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("images");
String url  = images.getJSONObject(resolution).getString("url");
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the images form the your JSON you need to understand how many JSONObject and JSONArray available in your josn result and keep follow the tree structure of your json result when you follow your json result structure you will get the images

Comment: I tried it already many times :p i have provided the result json, can you help with the code.